# Clojure installation error: Please delete these paths and run `brew update`

Tags: clojure, homebrew

I typed

```
brew install clojure
```

and I got the error below. What do I need to do? I don't know how to delete these paths. Sorry for the totally newbie question.

```
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
clojure: Java 1.8+ is required to install this formula.
JavaRequirement unsatisfied!
You can install with Homebrew-Cask:
brew cask install java
You can download from:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the paths, but you are clearly missing Java (which Clojure depends on) as you can see in the error message. Install it with `brew cask install java` as suggested and try running `brew install clojure` afterwards.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It startaed to install Java but it is asking for a password. Which pw is this? I tried my apple login but it did not accept. `Creating Caskroom at /usr/local/Caskroom
==> We'll set permissions properly so we won't need sudo in the future`

Comment: This should be your user's password. The same one `sudo` asks for.

Comment: I installed v.8 and that solved it. But I have another problem I'll ask separately.